# Is This an Accurate Maclaurin Expansion Method

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, differential

I believe I have found an alternative method for compacting the Maclaurin (easily extended to Taylor) series formula that may be preferable to some people.

To find the $n$th-order expansion of $f$, for each combination with replacement of $0$ to $n$ of $f$'s inputs, add a term consisting of that partial of $f$, times the iterated antiderivative of the corresponding differentials.  For example, the second-order expansion of $f(x,\ y)$ would be $f + f_x \int dx + f_y \int dy + f_{xx} \int\int dx\ dx + f_{xy} \int\int dx\ dy + f_{yy} \int\int dy\ dy$ (the first term doesn't appear to technically fit the pattern).  Note that this method considers combinations, not permutations, so the mixed partial only appears once.

Does this method work in general for any order expansion and any number of inputs $f$ may have?

Comment: Not really seeing what it happening here or how this is any simpler than the usual $\sum_\alpha\frac{D^\alpha f(0)}{\alpha!}\mathrm x^\alpha=\sum_n\frac1{n!}\left(\sum_ix_i\partial_{x_i}\right)^nf(0)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This would be the "symbol soup" approach.  The simplicity of the approach in the question would be 1) each term has only two factors, and 2) the visual symmetry between the two factors is helpful (you have one derivative factor and one antiderivative factor; once you write one, the other practically writes itself, i.e., starting with $f_{xxyz}$ the other factor is clearly $∫∫∫∫dx\ dx\ dy\ dz$.  To me, this is like the difference between memorizing and applying the determinant formula symbol by symbol, versus just computing the determinant.

Comment: How is this more of a "symbol soup" than what you have or lacking in visual symmetry? The usual is already very intuitive, just apply derivatives in different ways and multiply by that variable each time you differentiate.

Comment: Well it's ultimate subjective, of course.  My approach, if valid, is something that would be easier for me to recall.  From the premises that each term is 1) associated with a combination of the independent variables, and 2) the product of a partial derivative and antiderivative, what else would one write?  The derivative needs subscripts and the antiderivative needs differentials; just toss them right in there!

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but I don't see how this is simpler by any objective means. There are several objective reasons why the other forms should be used. For starters, it's already standard notation. Secondly, it only involves derivatives (why would you have integrals?). Third, it clearly shows that for each partial derivative taken you just multiply by that variable and divide by the factorial of the number of partial derivatives. It's straightforward to work out and gives a natural multinomial relationship.

Comment: To me at least what you've written is extremely unclear and it seems the question is subjective, so I'm voting to close it as such.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Fair enough.  I've removed the subjective portion of the question asking why this isn't commonly taught, in case that changes the decision to close.

Comment: I can't really understand your notation. What do the terms like $\int\int   dx dx$ mean?  I prefer the multinomial approach, it's easy to deal with and as it is used in so many other contexts. e.g. exterior algebra, one has to learn it anyway.

Comment: @Matematleta That just means take the antiderivative of $1\ dx$ with respect to $x$, then take the antiderivative of that with respect to $x$, so that one would be $\frac{1}{2}x^2$.

Comment: @user10478  OK, thanks!